# Can I use an if statement with multiple conditions? PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I bet I can, but would it work like this?

```
function dutchDateNames($) {
        $day = explode('-', $date)[2];
        $dutchday = ($day < 10) ? substr($day, 1) : $day;

        $month = explode('-', $date)[1];
        if ($month == '01' . '02') {
            $dutchmonth = 'Januari' . 'Februari';
        }

        $dutchdate = $dutchday . ' ' . $dutchmonth . ' ' . explode('-', $date)[0];
        return $dutchdate
    }
```

So, if `$month` is 01, $dutchmonth should be Januari. If $month is 02, $dutchmonth should be Februari, and so on.
I have the feeling I'm not doing this right?

Comment: use `switch` instead of `if` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: why don't you use `switch` case?

Answer (score 1):

Like thatyou would not return any month cause you concatenate (mounth 0102 does not exist).

If i correctly understand your question i think an array will be better :

```
$month = explode('-', $date)[1]; //Ok you use this data like an index

$letterMonth = ['01' => 'Januari', '02' => 'Februari', ....]; // Create an array with correspondance number -> letter month

$dutchmonth = $letterMonth[$month]; Get the good month using your index
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like something that could work the way I'd want it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use `elseif` conditions

```
if ($month == '01') {
    $dutchmonth = 'Januari';
} elseif ($month == '02') {
    $dutchmonth = 'Februari';
} elseif ($month == '03') {
   $dutchmonth = '...'; 
}
```

Comment: This seems highly inefficient :) But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create lookup array and get value by key:

```
$month = '02';
$months = [
    '01' => 'Januari'
    '02' => 'Februari'
    // more months here
];
$dutchmonth = isset($months[$month])? $months[$month] : '';
echo $dutchmonth;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way is to save the map a array. **[Demo](https://eval.in/763315)**

```
<?php
$array['01'] = 'Januari';
$array['02'] = 'Februari';
print_r($array);

echo $array[$month];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do any of these:

1. **if else**

   ```
   if ($month == "01") {
       $dutchmonth = "Januari";
   } else if($month == "02"){
       $dutchmonth = "Februari";
   }
   ```
2. **switch**

   ```
   switch($month) {
       case "01":
           $dutchmonth = "Januari";
           break;
       case "02":
           $dutchmonth = "Februari";
           break;
   }
   ```
3. **Using array**

   ```
   $month_arr = array('01' => "Januari", '02' => "Februari");
   $dutchmonth = $month_arr[$month];
   ```

**NOTE:** To use multiple `if` conditions use *logical operators* **&&** or **||**